# Issue with Accessing tabsetPanel Value in Shiny Module

Tags: r, shiny

I am encountering an issue trying to access the selected tab from a tabsetPanel in a Shiny module and was hoping to get some assistance.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
my_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = ns("tabSelector"),
      tabPanel("Land", value = "land", "Land Content"),
      tabPanel("Air", value = "air", "Air Content")
    )
  )
}

# Define Server
my_module_server <- function(output, input, session, notif_react) {
  ns <- session$ns

  observe({
    print(input$tabSelector)
  })
}

# App UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  my_module_ui("my_module")
)

# App Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(my_module_server, "my_module")
}

# Run App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run the app, it should theoretically print the value of the selected tab ("land" or "air") whenever it changes. However, this is not happening and I'm not receiving any output.

I'm observing the tabSelector and it should print its value. Unfortunately, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Warning: Error in $: Can't read output 'my_module-tabSelector'
```

Comment: As I pointed out yesterday, you are not setting up you module server correctly.  AND the order of the parameters you pass to your module server function is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the improvements and the use of moduleServer! I will take a deeper look at the parameter order and how I can integrate moduleServer into my Shiny app development. Your example is quite insightful and gives me a good direction to explore further.

Comment: Same thing than yesterday: put `my_module_ui("my_module")` inside `my_module_server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- You are defining your module server function incorrectly
- The parameters of your your "module server" are incorrectly ordered
- You are calling you module server incorrectly

*Please* read the online documentation on Shiny modules.  A good start is [here](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/modules/).

Here is a working version of your code.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
my_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
    tabsetPanel(
      id = ns("tabSelector"),
      tabPanel("Land", value = "land", "Land Content"),
      tabPanel("Air", value = "air", "Air Content")
    )
}

# Define Server
my_module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns

      observe({
        print(input$tabSelector)
      })
    }
  )
}

# App UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  my_module_ui("my_module")
)

# App Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_module_server("my_module")
}

# Run App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Personally, I'd use `observeEvent` rather than `observe` for exactly the same reasons that I mentioned yesterday.